# SSIS- Load destination Table with new column

Tags: ssis

We have one table (S1)  from database1 and are loading data into another database (datbase2) and table (D1).  We  implemented this in ssis  using OLEDB source (database1.S1) and OLEDB Destination (datbase2.D1).

We have to add a new column  '**Addeddate**' to destination table. For this we have used a Derived column in between source and destination.

Now my Thought is, instead of using a derived column can we create the added column in the source itself? because we need just record loaded date.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you use a SQL Query in your Source (and you should) all you have to do is add the column to the query.

Something like,

```
SELECT 
  S1.Column1, S1.Column2, ... S1.ColumnN, GETDATE() AS RecordLoadedDate
FROM S1
WHERE ...
```